# crontab not work in simple shell script but manually

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

My code didn't work in crontab. I installed new Raspberry Pi OS and write a simple shell script. It still do not work.

I added setup new Raspberry wrote a simple script hello.sh. Setup crontab run every 5 min and nothing happens.

**1. Raspberry Pi OS Lite (64 bit)**

```
pi@eve:~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
```

**2. shell script: hello.sh**

```
pi@eve:~ $ chmod 755 hello.sh
pi@eve:~ $ cat hello.sh
#!/bin/bash
# Program:
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin
export PATH
echo -e "Hello World! \a \n"
filename="text_file" # File name

date=$(date +%Y%m%d) # Today
file=${filename}${date} # add a file
touch "${file}"

exit 0
```

**3.setup crontab -e**

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
@reboot sleep 10; /usr/bin/printenv > /home/pi/cronenv.txt 2>&1
/5 * * * * /home/pi/hello.sh > /home/pi/cron.log 2>&1
```

**printenv**

```
pi@eve:~ $ cat cronenv.txt
HOME=/home/pi
LOGNAME=pi
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/home/pi
```

Note: Connect with SSH. Client is Windows 11 PowerShell

```
dos2unix hello.sh
```

Comment: Question is unclear.

Comment: I added setup new Raspberry wrote a simple script hello.sh. Setup crontab run every 5 min and nothing happens.

Comment: Does your script do what you expect when run directly from a shell?

Comment: print "Hollo world !" to /home/pi/cron.log  and a file , text_file.yymmdd

Answer (score 1):

There could be several reasons why your script is not working in crontab:

- The `crontab` *schedule* in your Q is WRONG: `/5 * * * *`. Fix it.
- Incorrect path: When you run a script from the command line, you may be in a different directory than when the script runs in crontab. Make sure that the full path to your script is specified in your crontab entry.
- Permissions: Make sure that your script has the correct permissions to be executed by the user specified in the crontab entry. You can set the permissions by running the command "chmod +x /path/to/your/script.sh".
- Environment variables: Cron runs in a limited environment, so any environment variables that your script needs may not be available. You can try to set these variables explicitly in your script or in the crontab entry.
- Output redirection: If your script produces any output, make sure that it is redirected to a file, as cron does not have a terminal to display the output.

Here is an example of a crontab entry that runs the script every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/your/script.sh >> /path/to/logfile.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Fixed crontab */5 * * * * , The issue was gone. Thanks !

Comment: @KevinLin: Glad I could help; perhaps you'd like to [do something to acknowledge that?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I did every as mentioned in this answer and still my script wont start at reboot. `@reboot /home/pi/myscript.sh`

Comment: @ThN: This answer does not address a `@reboot` job. My guess is that you've gotten something else wrong. Why don't you try asking a **new question** to make things clear?